# Create a "special" cover

Tags: covers

I'd like to create a cover similar to this:

[image]

I found it (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/imperial-college-london-phd-thesis-latex-template/zfybynnyczhb) but I can't make this work, I mean, I read the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\include{thesis.preamble}


\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE {\bf Title of my Ph.D. Thesis}\\
 \vspace*{6mm}
}

\author{Joe Bloggs}
\submitdate{October 2008}

\normallinespacing
\maketitle

\preface
\input{abstract/abstract}
\input{acknowledgements/acknowledgements}
\input{dedication/dedication}
\input{quotes/quotes}

\body
\input{introduction/introduction}
\input{background/background}

% body of thesis comes here

\input{conclusion/conclusion}

\appendix
% appendices come here


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography/bibliography}

\end{document}
```

But I'm not able to find where to change the university name and some other things, like the text in the bottom of the (first) page.

I don't know how to start.

Comment: And what is in the file "thesis.preamble"?

Comment: You can see the full code in: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/imperial-college-london-phd-thesis-latex-template/zfybynnyczhb Choose to open it as template. I don't know how it works beyond this point.

Comment: Indeed. But the policy on this site is to have, so far as possible, "self-contained" examples in an effort to make these questions and answers have some value independent of the fate of other websites.  (That said, I agree with @Johannes_B's answer.)

Answer (score 5):

Define you own titlepage. Much mor information can be found in [How to customize my titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907).

[image: francolinoTitlepage]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\Large
    University of London\par
    Some college\par
    Department of Computing\par
}
    \vfill
    {\Huge\bfseries
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers\par
}
\vspace{6ex}
{\Large
Walzing Wombat
\par}
\vfill
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\centering Submitted in fullfillment of something to get some fancy degree
in computing, some locale 2015}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```